# Python property instance behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, descriptor, python-internals

I know what is `property/descriptor` and `decorator`. But I have some hard time getting this point.

```py
class Person(object):
    @property
    def name(self, func):
        pass

    print("-- before setting -- ", name)

    @name.setter   # <---- what `name` object should be here
    def name(self, v):
        self._fn, self._ln = v.split(" ")

    print("-- before getting -- ", name)

    @name.getter  # <---- and here
    def name(self):
        return self._fn + " " + self._ln

    print("-- all done -- ", name) # <---- and here
```

`Descriptor` is class level object. So `@name.setter` and `@name.getter` should get same `name` descriptor object. When I add print statements after `setter` and `getter`, I am getting following result:

```py
('-- before setting -- ', <property object at 0x7fc1b0218f70>)  # (a)
('-- before getting -- ', <property object at 0x7fc1b0218fc8>) # (b)
('-- all done -- ', <property object at 0x7fc1b0218f70>) #(c)
```

(a) and (c) statements have same `property` object but (b) doesn't.

Can somebody explain me why is that or Am I missing something?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `getter`? It's usually not necessary; you just define the getter in the initial `@property` call.

Comment: I was just experimenting here. I created this fake scenario to introspect my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're 3 different property objects; the 3rd is just reusing the memory allocated for the first, since the first has been collected. When you use

```
@name.getter
```

or

```
@name.setter
```

the decorator returns a new property object reflecting the getter or setter you defined, which is then bound to the name of the function you're defining. Since the name of the function you're defining is `name`, it replaces the old `name` property.

Answer (score 1):

The decorators recreate the property object each time, combining the new information with the existing property. That the object IDs are the same in (a) and (c) is coincidence.